# Cross Product of Vectors

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hey everyone, I'm having trouble with this problem. I'm aware that the length is equal to the norm of v and w. And that the cross product is orthogonal to the vectors. I'm just not sure how to use what I know to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\vec{v} \times \vec{w}| = |\vec{v}||\vec{w}|\sin{\theta}$$

$$= 4 \times 4 \times \sin{\frac{\pi}{6}}$$

$$= 8$$

Thus the magnitude of the resultant vector is $8$. As for the direction, we know the cross product will be perpendicular to the plane created by the other two vectors. Specifically, it will be parallel to the $y$ axis, pointing in the negative direction.

Comment: $4\cdot 4\cdot\sin\frac{\pi}{6}=8$ not $4$.

Comment: But shouldn't the answer of a cross product be a vector?

Comment: Yes, it is a vector.  Sim's solution tells you the magnitude of the vector; as the second paragraph says, the direction is in the positive *y*-direction.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbf{v\times w}=\mathbf{||v||\cdot||w||}\sin \theta\mathbf{n}\\
\implies \mathbf{v\times w}=8\mathbf{n}$$

Comment: I do not understand where you got n from? Also, isn't the result of a cross product a vector? 8n is a scalar if I'm not mistaken

Comment: No, **n** denotes a unit normal *vector* -- that is, a vector that points out from the plane in which **v** and **w** are contained.  (In this case, though, **n** = $\hat{j}$.)

Comment: @Shenuque The cross product of two vectors $v$ and $w$ results in a third vector $u$ which is orthogonal to both $v$ and $w$. The main difficulty lies in the fact that without being given $v$ and $w$, how do you know how long the vector should be? This is what the sin formula handles for you.